# Display form data on same page as data is entered using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm pretty good at php mysql and html. I'm just learning jquery and need some help. What I want to do is as values are entered on a page, specifically a check box list, print those values on the same page as the check box are selected. How do I go about doing this using jquery? Or javascript cause I'm learning that too? Or point me to a tutorial that will help.

Comment: Pretty much any PHP/AJAX tutorial will give you the general idea of what you're trying to do. You use JavaScript to add event listeners onclick for the checkboxes, then when the event fires you modify some HTML element. Just work through 1 tutorial, get the general idea, then work towards a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code to copy billing address to shipping address

```
<script>
function copyToBill(){
   var address = document.getElementById("copied_id").value;
   document.getElementById("posted_id").value=address;
 }
</script>
```

checkbox:

```
<legend class="checkout_legend">Fatura Bilgileri 
  <span class="label label-success pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="copyToBill();">Adresi kopyala</span>
</legend>
```

and thats all it is. You're getting the value of copied_id and setting to posted_id. Call this function onclick.